# Meteor State Machine

Tags: javascript, meteor, state-machine

I've implemented Nate Strauser's State Machine (https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-statemachine). I get the FSM to save it's state to the DB successfully but I'm tracking several instances. In my example, I'm tracking the shift status of workers.

I want the system to load states for each on meteor startup. Then, I want to make a state change request upon the state machine instance and have it update the status of the DB document (if that change is allowed).

How do I marry FSM instances to the actual Shift instances? Am I approaching this the wrong way? Any thoughts appreciated.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

var machineEvents = [
    { name: 'toggleduty',  from: 'Off_Duty',      to: 'On_Duty_Idle' },
    { name: 'toggleduty',  from: 'On_Duty_Idle',  to: 'Off_Duty' },
    { name: 'toggleduty',  from: 'On_Duty_Busy',  to: 'Off_Duty_Busy' },
    { name: 'toggleduty',  from: 'Off_Duty_Busy', to: 'On_Duty_Busy' },
    { name: 'togglebusy',  from: 'On_Duty_Idle',  to: 'On_Duty_Busy' },
    { name: 'togglebusy',  from: 'On_Duty_Busy',  to: 'On_Duty_Idle' },
    { name: 'togglebusy',  from: 'Off_Duty_Busy', to: 'Off_Duty' },
    { name: 'start',       from: 'Init',          to: 'On_Duty_Idle' },];

var machineCallbacks = {
    ontoggleduty: function(event, from, to, shift) {
        console.log('Toggling Duty', shift);
        Shifts.update(shift._id, {$set: { 'status':to }});
    },
    ontogglebusy: function(event, from, to, shift) {
        console.log('Toggling Busy', shift);
        Shifts.update(shift._id, {$set: { 'status':to }});
    },
};


var makeStateMachine = function(shift){
    console.log('new state machine generating');
    var stateMachine = StateMachine.create({
        initial: shift.status,
        events: machineEvents,
        callbacks: machineCallbacks
    });
    switch (shift.state) {
        case "Init":
            console.log('Init to On_Duty_Idle',shift);
            stateMachine.start(shift);
            break;
    }
};

// function killStateMachine(shift){  // not sure how to kill the specific reference
//     stateMachine = null;
// }

//look for new state machines
Shifts.find({'status': 'Init'}).observe({
    added: makeStateMachine,
    //removed: killStateMachine
});

// In the mongo shell I trigger with db.statemachines.insert({_id:'driver1', state:'start'})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in a fork of the original state machine, that adds a transitionTo method, allowing any state to be selected - which I think is what you want in restoring the state from the database. I have a fork which consolidates a few other peoples changes

https://github.com/mikkelking/javascript-state-machine

You could clone natestrauser's package locally in your project to refer to my repo (although I haven't done a release of it). I am intending to do a pull request at some point once my changes are stable (which they seem to be).